# How to chain validations with pydantic

Tags: python, json, validation, pydantic

Let's say I have webhook where I get json data. This json is recursively converted by pydantic.

```
@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
async def telegram_webhook(request):
    update = Update.parse_obj(request.json)
    /* do something with update */
```

I check this json is *minimal* valid object with **Update** model (which internally contains **Message** model):

```
class Update(BaseModel):
    update_id: int
    message: Message
    ...

class Message(BaseModel):
    message_id: int
    text: Optional[str]
```

But later in the code I want to **extend** validation, so to check that *message* is not only **Message**, but **TextMessage**:

```
// text field now is required
class TextMessage(Message):
    text: str

    @validator('text')
    def check_text_length(cls, value):
        length = len(value)
        if length > 4096:
            raise ValueError(f'text length {length} is too large')
        return value
```

So I pass message to validation function

```
def process_text_message(message):
    text_message = TextMessage.parse_obj(message)
```

But I get error that **pydantic** requires not **Message** type, but **dict**.

How would I do that?
How could I apply additional validation on already validated (basically) data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: use `message.dict()`:

```
def process_text_message(message):
    text_message = TextMessage.parse_obj(message.dict())
```

The longer answer is that `parse_obj` should be fixed to cope with "dict-like" things not just dicts, I'll explain that on [the issues you created](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/472).